# Node Nodemon Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

- I am a beginner at NodeJS stuff.
- Environment is Windows 7 64 Bit.
- Node is installed and working.
- NPM is also working fine.
- Nodemon is installed. (In App and also Globally)

Now when I run the command:

> "nodemon server.js" or just "nodemon"

it gives the following error:

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

- I don't understand what this means? And why is it looking inside the Git folder?
- Does it have to do anything with Environment Variable? But Node and NPM are both working fine.
- Any ideas/suggestion/solution?

Below is my "server.js" file in case you need for reference.

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var morgan = require("morgan");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, es, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization");
    next();
});

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log(">>>>> App is Running <<<<<");
```

Comment: have you installed nodemon? I recommend you not install it globally. Use command npm install --save nodemon. Then go to your package.json, put this line in your scripts "server": "nodemon server.js". Finally, npm run server to run your app

Comment: Write a Nodejs Script that just console.log("hello") and run that with nodemon (no other includes, no logic) and see what happens

Comment: please try to do this
" npm install --save -g nodemon "

-g flag will install it globally

Comment: Hey Guys. I tried everything. Installing Locally, installing globally, running App with just "console.log()". Even altering "package.json" file. But no matter what, it's giving the same error when I run any command with nodemon.

Comment: I inserted the line "start": "nodemon server.js" in the scripts section of package.json. Now, when I run the command "npm start", it is Working. This is similar to what is suggested by @dnp1204. I don't know what was the issue with the current configuration, but this worked. Thanks to all of you for trying to help me out. Appreciated.

Comment: The issue is you had install the nodemon but not on the correct path.

Comment: How to check the path and what should be the default path? Because now when I am trying to run "karma init", I am getting the same error. I have installed karma and all the dependencies along with karma cli.

Comment: It seems that, this is an issue with MINGW64. If I utilize Windows CMD to run the commands, everything is working fine. Hope this might helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

remove  node_modules in your project and than install reagain nodemon module, run below commands;

```html
rm -rf node_modules
npm install -g npm@latest
npm i nodemon
```

Comment: you are suggesting removing the entire node_modules dir. Thats a bad practice! node_modules might have hundreds of gigabytes of dependencies that have nothing to see with the problematic dependency and you end up creating more problems by reinstalling those.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was same issue I solved it by mentioned method hope it will
help you so in package.json in script tag

```
  "start":"nodemon index.js"
```

and in terminal with this command run

```
  nodemon start
```

Answer (score 0):

you must validate that the server name (servers.js) is called the same inside the folder, ( package.json ) validate **main** and **start** you should not create folders for nodemon.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are running the server.js is in the root directory and run this command in root directory of your project

```
nodemon ./server.js
```

Also you can rename server.js to index.js and just run

```
nodemon
```

More on nodemon:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Comment: You can also set your current working directory inside the script with `process.chdir(__dirname);`, make sure to put it at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

Use command: `npm run server` and not nodemon server.js  you  will get exact error that which module is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a typical path problem. You need to fix your environment variable PATH for npm to execute correctly.

the path you need to add looks like: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`

Find the PATH env var and add the path you expect your npm packages to install from!

Or you can navigate to that directory and execute: `npm config set prefix`

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon is looking for the main config in the package.json, Which may be missing.
try to add main property in package.json with the key of your entry file.
for example:-

```
"main":"src/main.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

"start": "nodemon src/app.js"

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall current nodemon and try to install nodemon globally, then run it again.

`npm i nodemon -g`

Answer (score 0):

Please check your parent folder name - the folder name or any file name should not contain any symbol like %^&*#$ if contains means this kind of error will occur